# How can I prevent dropdown menu hide when clicking on a popover triggered from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover triggered by a dropdown menu using the standard Twitter Bootstrap javascript components.

Can you help me prevent the dropdown from closing while a user clicks on the popover?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EAdW5/

UX:

1. Click dropdown menu button `===>` Dropdown menu displays
2. Click popover dropdown item `===>` Popover displays
3. Click Popover `===>` Dropdown menu and popover disappears!  **O no!  How can I prevent this?**

I'd like the popover and dropdown to remain up until (a) click outside dropdown and popover, or (b) deliberate hide (after clicking popover form submit, for example).

html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="btnId" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Regular Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regular Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="popoverId" class="popoverThis">Popover Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="hide" id="popover-custom-content">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="control-group">
            <textarea name="issue"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <button id="btnPopoverSubmitId" class="btn">Add</button>
            <span class="close close-inline">Cancel</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#popoverId').popover({
    html:true,
    placement: 'right',
    title: "Popover Title",
    template: '<div id="popover-custom-content" class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    content: function() { return $('#popover-custom-content').html(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap DROPDOWN class definition, the dropdown is registered as active using $parent.toggleClass('open'). In this case it adds the class 'open' to the btn-group div which is the parent of your 'btnId' element.

You could prevent the default DROPDOWN show/hide toggle, and override it using $('.btn-group').show(); to keep it shown, regardless of the Bootstrap default behavior.

Then use $('.btn-group').hide() on a custom 'mousedown' event of yours, as well as on a 'mouseout' of the btn-group node, to restore the default Bootstrap behavior.

Or, you may also check the jQuery event.stopPropagation() or event.stopImmediatePropagation() to prevents the click event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/